# Displays tables that are already stored in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, local-storage

i want to create New Content. the *New content* is dataTable and will be saved to localStorage

When i click the **ADD NEW TABLE** button, the Table has created and saved to localStorage.

**BUT**

> When im refresh the page, The table not display but saved to
>   localStorage.

[**MY JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/gtwnueq8/)

> **How to be able to display a table [datatable view] that has been created** and stored in localStorage when the page is refreshed?

**jQuery :**

```
$("#mainTable").dataTable();

/* CREATE TABLE FITURE */
$('.submitButton').click(function() {
  function getTableList() {
    var addTable = '<div class="tab-pane" id="folder' + localStorage.Index + '">' +
      '<div class="zf-table">' +
      '<table id="table' + localStorage.Index + '" class="table table-bordered table-hover myFade">' +
      '<thead>' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<th style="border-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);"></th>' +
      '<th>Audience Name</th>' +
      '<th>Type</th>' +
      '<th>Size</th>' +
      '<th>Date Created</th>' +
      '<th>Action</th>' +
      '</tr>' +
      '</thead>' +
      '</table>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';
    return addTable;
  }

  if (true) {
    /** INDEX FOR INCREMENT ID **/
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      if (localStorage.Index) {
        localStorage.Index = Number(localStorage.Index) + 1;
      } else {
        localStorage.Index = 1;
      }
    } // if storage

    var resultTable = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tableList"));
    if (resultTable == null) {
      resultTable = [];
    }
    let newtableHTML = getTableList();
    resultTable.push({
      table: newtableHTML
    });
    // save the new resultTable array
    localStorage.setItem("tableList", JSON.stringify(resultTable));

    /* append Table baru */
    $('.tab-content').append(newtableHTML);
    var newTable = $("#table" + localStorage.Index).dataTable();
    alert("sucess create table");

  } else {
    alert("Failed create Table");
  }
}); // submitButton func

//on init fill the table-content

var resultTable = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tableList"));
if (resultTable != null) {
  //get the nav reference in DOM
  let tableContent = $(".tab-content");

  //clear the html contents
  tableContent.html('');

  for (var i = 0; i < resultTable.length; i++) {
    var items = resultTable[i];
    $(".tab-content").append(items.table);
  }
} else {
  let inititalTable = [];
  inititalTable.push({
    table: $('div.tab-content').html()
  });
  localStorage.setItem("tableList", JSON.stringify(inititalTable));
}
```

Comment: You should first check your Javascript and make sure it's free from errors.

Two errors I see:
1. `let tableContent = $(".table-content");`: there is no element in your HTML with this selector, so nothing can be `append`ed.
2. Check you console, it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined`. It refers to this line `$(".tab-content").append(item.table);` and should be `items` I guess.

Comment: haha, im typo. sorry.. but that makes my default table not display. and unsolved .

Comment: i already update post and [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/gtwnueq8/). work but unsolved, the table display like [This](http://prntscr.com/hjb4b7). should i stored `var newTable` to localStorage too?

Answer (score 0):

seems you forgot to call `dataTable()` on the table elements read from LocalStorage.

By looping through the stored tables with

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultTable.length; i++) {
    var items = resultTable[i];
    $(".tab-content").append(items.table);
}
```

you only append the initial HTML. It must be transformed by the dataTables plugin afterwards to show ordering, searching and paging features.

A possible solution would be calling `dataTable()` on all tables in tab-content container after the for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultTable.length; i++) {
    var items = resultTable[i];
    $(".tab-content").append(items.table);
}

$(".tab-content table").dataTable();
```

Comment: i cant show the page, i got an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined`

Comment: great, but i need to delete default datatable first to make another table working. that make my default table not display datatable view.